# ios, problems with static table view labeling on cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

when I put a label on my static cell it does not stay in the view.

What it looks like in storyboard. [image]

What it looks like on the simulator. 
[image]

[image]

I'm trying to add a textField too. 
[image]

thanks for any help.

Comment: Please post the source code as zip if possible.

Comment: This is just being done in storyboard. I'm using a custom cell. I add a label and text view  the the content view of the cell. @Harry

Comment: What cell style are you using? Basic?

Comment: custom cell style @Harry

Comment: Are you using UITableViewController?

Comment: Yes I am using that @Harry

Comment: have used the table view heightForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: The static cells will just shown same as design in storyboard without any additional code. I suggest you to check any code related with the table view.

Comment: I have been adjusting the height of the cell in storyboards to see if that does anything, but does not seem to fix the problem. @Alex

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps xcode has a bug? I'm not sure, but I had to add constraints to my label and textField in order for them to stay in the table view cell. All is well.